# What happens to your pulse rate when you are in zero gravity in space?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, space, biology, space-mission

I am new to stack exchange, this is my first post. To start with, what happens to your blood pulse rate when you are in zero gravity?

Does it increase or decrease?
I thought a lot about this but am confused about the gravity's role in opposing blood flowing up. In space there's no gravity, so blood flows faster without any opposition. Am I right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: worth noting: there is gravity in space, thats why the earth orbits the sun and why the ISS orbits the earth

Comment: Gravity does not affect a flow of liquid in a closed circuit, because for any amount moving down, there is an equal amount moving up on the opposite side. However, gravity affects the muscle tension and this does make it easier for the heart to push the blood through the body. As a result, the heart rate stays about the same, if very slightly slower (2-4%), but the amplitude drops down nearly twice. After the flight, the heart rate increases by close to 20% and the amplitude returns to normal. Details here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214552415000024

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about biology rather than physics.

Comment: The pulse rate is determined by the ability of you heart. So it is not significantly affected but the body needs to adapt. More details here https://www.nasa.gov/vision/earth/livingthings/arterial_remodel.html